# Updating the DOM based on scroll position with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: dom, position, twitter-bootstrap

If you look at this page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html

Note the submenu and it's position. Now scroll down - notice how it changes? I assumed they implemented it with the scrollspy plugin but I can't seem to figure out how to do it, all I can do is update which list element has the active class.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find this bit of code in the application.js file, it doesn't look as though it's included in the download. It's available [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/application.js)...funnily enough the header comment reads

```
// NOTICE!! DO NOT USE ANY OF THIS JAVASCRIPT
// IT'S ALL JUST JUNK FOR OUR DOCS!
// ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

This is the part that does the heavy lifting I believe...haven't tested it, just stepped through the code in Chrome

```
// fix sub nav on scroll
var $win = $(window)
  , $nav = $('.subnav')
  , navTop = $('.subnav').length && $('.subnav').offset().top - 40
  , isFixed = 0

processScroll()

$win.on('scroll', processScroll)

function processScroll() {
  var i, scrollTop = $win.scrollTop()
  if (scrollTop >= navTop && !isFixed) {
    isFixed = 1
    $nav.addClass('subnav-fixed')
  } else if (scrollTop <= navTop && isFixed) {
    isFixed = 0
    $nav.removeClass('subnav-fixed')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CCBlackburn's answer is close though its missing the required stylesheet. For posterity I've also included the javascript. Anyway I got it working using the following:

Javascript

```
// fix sub nav on scroll
var $win = $(window)
  , $nav = $('.subnav')
  , navTop = $('.subnav').length && $('.subnav').offset().top - 40
  , isFixed = 0

processScroll()

// hack sad times - holdover until rewrite for 2.1
$nav.on('click', function () {
  if (!isFixed) setTimeout(function () {  $win.scrollTop($win.scrollTop() - 47) }, 10)
})

$win.on('scroll', processScroll)

function processScroll() {
  var i, scrollTop = $win.scrollTop()
  if (scrollTop >= navTop && !isFixed) {
    isFixed = 1
    $nav.addClass('subnav-fixed')
  } else if (scrollTop <= navTop && isFixed) {
    isFixed = 0
    $nav.removeClass('subnav-fixed')
  }
}
```

Stylesheet

```
/* Fixed subnav on scroll, but only for 980px and up (sorry IE!) */
@media (min-width: 980px) {
  .subnav-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1020; /* 10 less than .navbar-fixed to prevent any overlap */
    border-color: #d5d5d5;
    border-width: 0 0 1px; /* drop the border on the fixed edges */
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
       -moz-border-radius: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
       -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false); /* IE6-9 */
  }
  .subnav-fixed .nav {
    width: 938px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1px;
  }
  .subnav .nav > li:first-child > a,
  .subnav .nav > li:first-child > a:hover {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
       -moz-border-radius: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
  }
}

/* LARGE DESKTOP SCREENS */
@media (min-width: 1210px) {

  /* Update subnav container */
  .subnav-fixed .nav {
    width: 1168px; /* 2px less to account for left/right borders being removed when in fixed mode */
  }

}
```